# Exercise on Haar systems

Tags: probability-theory, analysis

Let $f\in L^p[0,1]$ for $p\geq1$ and let $H_n$ be the Haar system on $[0,1]$. Let also $S_n(x,f)=\sum_{r=0}^{n}{\alpha_rH_r(x)}$, where $\alpha_r=\int_{0}^{1}{H_r(x)f(x)dx}$. Now I would like to show that $\mathbb{E}[f\mid\mathcal{F}_n]=S_n(x,f)$. Does anyone have any ideas how this could be proven? I know that the Haar functions are an orthonormal system, but I haven't been able to use this in a proper manner in order to accomplish the proof. Here the probability measure is the Lebesgue measure restricted to $[0, 1]$,
and $\mathcal{F}_n=\sigma(H_0,H_1,...,H_n)$.